# Is this an efficient way of reordering HTML with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, insertafter

The script below checks the browser width and moves some divs around if it detects the css element `text-align:center` on a dom element.  This css element is dependent on a media query for 980px. The code works without a hitch but I feel like maybe there was a simpler way of doing this.  I am aware this probably could have been accomplished in CSS through floats but felt like this would be a cleaner way of doing it.   Any advice regarding how to make this code more efficient would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function moveDiv(){
    var $window = $(window);
    var windowsize = $window.width();

    if (windowsize < 980) {
      if ($(".interiortitle h1").css("text-align") == "center"){
        $( ".interiorpage .et_pb_column_1_4").insertAfter(".interiorpage .et_pb_column_3_4");
      }
    }
    else if (windowsize > 980) {
      $( ".interiorpage .et_pb_column_1_4").insertBefore(".interiorpage .et_pb_column_3_4");
    }
   }
   moveDiv();
   $(window).resize(moveDiv);
});
```

Comment: CSS floats or media queries would be much much **much** more efficient than any Javascript you could write to do this.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RGraham: but css can't reorganize the dom. look at the two conditions. one's `insertAfter`, the other's `insertBefore`. css can't tweak the tree like that.

Comment: @MarcB Of course. But with a little creativity, CSS can certainly make it *look* as if the DOM has been reorganized. And it will be much more performant. Also, OP stated `this probably could have been accomplished in CSS through floats`...

Comment: [CSS flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) can reorganize blocks even better than floats can. Might be what you need.

Comment: @RGraham I know that using CSS for something like this would be more efficient overall and you could probably accomplish the same thing.  I'm only interested in making this script as efficient as possible.

Comment: A way of doing this is actually using a CSS parameter to retrieve in jQuery for processing. What you can do is create an empty div, set it's position to absolute within the body (but no other element) and give it a width and set its z-index to like negative a million or something. Then in CSS set its width for every media query you have. In jQuery retrieve the width information for that specific element and then apply styling accordingly. Oh and hide it, make its visibility hidden, etc.

Comment: @Blazemonger I love flexbox and know of its magical powers but alas am using a Wordpress theme built on floats.

Comment: Oh, another way to do this that I just thought of, is to actually create different websites for each device, and then set a container for each of these websites and put them all on the same page, and in new css file you can set media queries to show specific ids (websites) based on browser viewport sizes. So as an example for someone viewing on 1000px wide browser window, having a div wrapping the mobile version of your site with id of *container_mobile_version* and set it to `display:none` and set the div for your full sized site to `display:block` (i.e. id of *container_full_version*)

Comment: (ran out of room) but I would recommend against doing that if it's possible. It may be cleaner, but will (likely) take longer to load unless you plan to use js do create that.

Comment: Learn/Use Bootstrap man you will thank me  http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could try this out:

Check if your window size has changed and apply a new class for your div:

```
var changeposdiv= $('.changeposdiv');

var $window = $(window);
var windowsize = $window.width();

if (windowsize > 980) {
    changeposdiv.addClass('more980');
}
```

Your HTML example

```
<div class="interiordiv">
    ABC
</div>
<div class="changeposdiv">
    Change it
</div>
```

And CSS will move elements in user's screen

```
.changeposdiv, .interiordiv {
    float: left
}

.more980 {
    float: right;
}
```

Does it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsbin.com/saviliwixe/1/edit?html,css,output)? As you change the width of the page, the red and green columns swap sides.

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="interiorpage">
    <div class="et_pb_column_1_4"></div>
    <div class="et_pb_column_3_4"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.interiorpage{
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
}
div[class^=et_pb_column_]{
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
}
.et_pb_column_1_4{
 background: #fcc;
 order: 2;
 -webkit-order: 2;
}
.et_pb_column_3_4{
 background: #cfc;
 order: 1;
 -webkit-order: 1;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  .et_pb_column_1_4{
   order: 1;
   -webkit-order: 1;
  }
  .et_pb_column_3_4{
    order: 2;
   -webkit-order: 2;
  }
}
```